# Importing Sitemap from Liferay 7.0 to Liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, sitemap, liferay-7

Is there a way to **import** a **LAR file** (Sitemap) from Liferay 7.0 to Liferay 6.2?

I tried to Edit LAR file, i opened it and I edited Manifest.xml and I changed `build-number="7002"` from to `build-number="6205`"

[image]

But it doesn't work :

[image]

Is there a way or a "Hack" to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Technically there is a way to hack it: make it appear as exactly the expected version.

However, that's an unrealistic answer, because LAR files are meant for *exactly* the same version. Even a 6.2GA3 installation *will* reject a 6.2GA4 LAR file.

I'm not aware of the exact changes, but given that the whole architecture changed dramatically between 6.2 and 7, I'd expect this not to be a trivial thing. As LAR files are *only* meant to *ever* be used in communication between instances of *exactly* the same version, the file content is also not documented. Rather it's documented to be free to change at will. It is what is *currently* needed.

If you'd go the other way (6.2 -> 7) the recipe would be to update your 6.2 instance and export the LAR again. But it's not an established usecase to update older versions with the content from newer versions - that'd be a downgrade. Authoring systems (e.g. staging) should be on the same version as the production installation.